# Gulp not watching .scss files?

Tags: sass, npm, gulp, watch

I'm setup as outlined below. The good news: styles are being compiled, the bad news: gulp doesn't seem to watch the scss files for a change and compile automatically?

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'); 


// Plugins
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var stripDebug = require('gulp-strip-debug');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var include = require('gulp-include');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');

// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('./_themes/blanktheme/ui/scss/styles.scss')
        .pipe(include())
        .pipe(sass({
            errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./_themes/blanktheme/ui/css/'))
});


// Watch
gulp.task('default', ['watch'], function() {
    gulp.watch('./_themes/blanktheme/ui/scss/*.scss', ['styles']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this come from the fact you have two tasks `default`. I guess gulp ignore the first one (with `gulp.watch`) to only trigger the second one. Then you have dependencies with watch but seems like watch does not exist ?

You can install gulp-watch locally, and include it in your file. Give a look at [gulp-watch documentation](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch) it might help.

Try this :D

```
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('./_themes/blanktheme/ui/scss/styles.scss')
        .pipe(include())
        .pipe(sass({
            errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./_themes/blanktheme/ui/css/'))
});


// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    watch('./_themes/blanktheme/ui/scss/*.scss', function () {
        gulp.start('styles');
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Sebastien, just tried it, but sadly it didn't work :(

Very new to gulp, so stupid questions alert: 

Do I need to install gulp-watch globally? Or does the watch function ship with gulp?

Also, if it was working I would expect to see gulp styles run in terminal right?

Comment: You do not need to install it globally, but you will need to import it in your gulpefile. I updated my answer it should work for you now, it should appear in your console yes. Gulp is a great tool, hope you will like using it.